# C/C++, отсутствие default в switch и UB

Tags: c++, c, switch, неопределённое-поведение

Подскажите, является ли отсутствие `default` в `switch` неопределенным поведением, если в `switch` попадает значение, для которого нет соответствующего `case`?

Comment: Почему неопределённое? Если нет совпадений - выход из блока `switch`

Comment: Где-то видел такую информацию, вот и мне интересно.

Comment: @Максим Присваивайте вопросам правильные метки. Вы уже в который раз изобретаете `сс++` вместо того, чтобы добавить `c` и `c++` по отдельности.

Comment: Нет, хотя некоторые компиляторы могут выдавать предупреждение, что не все варианты обрабатываются.

Comment: @zed [Вы уже в который раз изобретаете сс++ вместо того, чтобы добавить c и c++ по отдельности.] Кстати не так уж и глупо иметь общую метку для c/c++. Это позволяет экономить метки коих, как известно, под вопросом может быть только пять штук. Имея общую метку для c/c++ можно под вопросом иметь как-бы шесть меток. Только я бы назвал эту метку именно c/c++ через слэш, а не сс++ без разделителей. Все-таки через слэш более привычно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 метку со слешем нельзя создать. По поводу 6 меток - обычно 2-4 хватает. Если вам нужно больше 6, значит вы в метки что-то лишнее засовываете.

Comment: [метку со слешем нельзя создать] Вот красавцы! Мало того что в 21 веке вручную предлагают html редактировать, так еще и ограничения на набор символов имеется.

Comment: @insolor [Если вам нужно больше 6, значит вы в метки что-то лишнее засовываете.] Вот именно шесть меток это и есть сакральное число? Не больше не меньше?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 4 метки хватит для большинства вопросов. +2 - запас. В итоге 6 - вполне достаточно для любого вопроса.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 такого языка не существует. Си и Си++ не совместимы в ряде вопросов, особеннно с каламбурами, пребразованием типов или псевдонимами и использованием некоторых ключевых слов. Общая метка недопустима

Comment: @Swift Общая метка вполне допустима, если вопрос касается общих вещей для Си и С++. А таких вопросов предостаточно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, поведение вполне определенное - если нет подходящих веток `case` и отсутствует `default`, то ни один из блоков не выполняется.

> Из рабочего черновика C++20(N4762)
>   **8.4.2 The switch statement**
>   ...
>
> 5. When the switch statement is executed, its condition is evaluated and compared with each case constant. If one of the case constants is equal to the value of the condition, control is passed to the statement following the matched case label. If no case constant matches the condition, and if there is a default label, control passes to the statement labeled by the default label. If no case matches and if there is no default then none of the statements in the switch is executed.

Однако, компиляторы могут выдавать предупреждения, если в `switch` обрабатываются не все случаи.

Comment: Не плохо бы указать ссылку, откуда вы взяли цитату.

Comment: @zed добавил в ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: `Документ N4762` это конечно сильно) Ну ок, хотя бы так.

Comment: @zed перефразировал